# "PSAD config File Does Not Contain Email Address" however, it does

Tags: 16.04, server, security, email, firewall

I installed PSAD and I attempted to configure the system. I set my email address and my hostname, however, every time I run psad I get this error:

```
"[*] The config file "/etc/psad/psad.conf" does not contain the
variable: "EMAIL_ADDRESSES".  Exiting! at /usr/sbin/psad line 10637."
```

I've tried searching the documentation, but I haven't found anything that relates to this on the website.

My second question is should I enable Auto_IDS? Every setup site I go to says do this at your own risk, but they don't explain what it does.

My system is Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS.

Any help would be appreciative.

**Updated Info:**

In addition to my issues, I am experiencing this when I do **sudo psad -R** or **sudo psad -H**.

```
Possible precedence issue with control flow operator at /usr/sbin/fwcheck_psad line 193.
```

Every search I do comes up with an issue with the firewall. I attempted these settings and it still comes up.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG
sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -j LOG
sudo ip6tables -A FORWARD -j LOG

sudo nano /etc/ufw/before.rules
sudo nano /etc/ufw/before6.rules
```

I added the following in the files before the commit line.

```
# custom psad logging directives
-A INPUT -j LOG --log-tcp-options --log-prefix "[IPTABLES] "
-A FORWARD -j LOG --log-tcp-options --log-prefix "[IPTABLES] "
```

I saved and restarted UFW, no luck. I rebooted the server and no luck as well.

Comment: To answer your second question, read [this](http://www.cipherdyne.org/psad/docs/config.html#ENABLE_AUTO_IDS).

Comment: This is a sadly outdated psad tutorial, at least this is how I config and use psad - http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/psad

Comment: @Panther How do I effectively remove it? Use `sudo apt-get remove psad`?

Comment: `sudo apt purge psad` , assuming you installed from repos. psad is fairly easy, you have to read the tutorials and the comments in the config file. If you need help you really need to pastebin your config file.

Comment: I attempted to install using the scripts but I am not sure how to remove the files and start over again.